# ASP.NET confirm dialog not working the second time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a form where I have a dropdownlist and many labels. When I select an option from dropdownlist it fetched data from database related to that option and populates them to field. Then I have a delete button. When I click on this that particular selected field from list will be deleted from database. For this before deleting whenever I click on delete button it ask for popup confirm dialog and when I click OK it will delete. I am using the below code for this.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("You really want to delete the data?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**C#**

```
protected void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        // delete data from database
    }
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Button ID="button_delete" Visible="false" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="Confirm()" OnClick="button_delete_Click" />
```

Initially the delete button is set to `visible=false` and only after selecting an item from list it becomes visible. Does this affect the confirm dialog after postback or something? It is working the first time and after I reload the page manually and try it works. But when I do it continuously without reloading page it wont work the second time. What is the issue here?

Comment: Is there any error in browser console in second time?

Comment: call Confirm()  function on  $(document).ready(function () {Confirm()}); 
and please check any error in browser console

Comment: When you run the confirm() method first time, it append the hidden field to the form. with value "Yes" or "No" depend on you selection. Then when you run the confirm() method second time, it will append another hidden field. When it comes down to the backend button_delete_click, the Request.Form["confirm_value"] may not be the one you expect.

Comment: no, no error in console

Comment: @Jonathon is there any way to clear the field each time?

Comment: when i use within `$(document).ready(function () { });` i am getting this error `The value of the property 'Confirm' is null or undefined, not a Function object`

Comment: @ManoPrathibhanC, what you can do is check if there is input with name equals "confirm_value", if not, then create one. Otherwise, update the value of the existing hidden field.

Comment: You have used Page_ClientValidate. So when all validation satisfied then only it ask for confirm dialog

Comment: @Jonathon how can i do that? can u send me as suitable code for my case?

Comment: @BharatsingParmar yes but i am satisfying all conditions..if i dont use Page_ClientValidate then my required field validator wont get fired...i removed Page_ClientValidate  and tried but still same issue

Comment: Try and debug the JS code in the browser, Check if the code block within if is executed.

Comment: i cant find any issue here..is there any other alternate way for this? using JQuery or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Confirm to return a true or false value depending on the condition.

```html
function Confirm() {

    var isFormValid = Page_ClientValidate();
    var isConfirmedByUser = confirm("You really want to delete the data?");

    //returns true when form is valid and user confirms action
    return (isFormValid  && isConfirmedByUser);               
}
```

and change the OnClientClick to

```html
<asp:Button ID="button_delete" Visible="true" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Confirm();" OnClick="button_delete_Click" />
```

when the Confirm() return a false value to OnClientClick it should not do a postback.

Comment: I tried this also but doesnt work..maybe i didnt try like the way u meant..can u send me a clear code using my question?

Comment: Just replace the Confirm method with the above and change the button_delete's OnClientClick to `return Confirm();` that should do it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: this is not even doing anything..inside Confirm() u are only firing the confirm box to open..u did not mention what happen when we click ok..so nothing happens here

Comment: the confirm box ok click will return true and so the Confirm() function will return true to `OnClientClick`. This should execute the `OnClick` postback call

Comment: oh ok let me try again

Comment: I tried on a project in my machine and it seems to be working fine. I'll update the answer with full code snippets.

Comment: anytime, no problem :)